# Dynamic value for CASE in java SWITCH

Tags: java, dynamic, switch-statement

I need to implement switch case statement with dynamic value for case as below.

```
int v1 = 5;
int key = xx.getKey();

switch (v1) {
   case key:
       .......
   case key+1:
       .......
   case key+2:
       .......
   default:
       .......
}
```

When using this, java complains "case expressions must be constant expressions". Is there a way to use dynamic values in case. (switch variable is also dynamic value)

Comment: No, there is not. You can use [Andy Turner's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32733087/2071828) suggesting in this case. In the general case you would have to use a `if...else if...else`.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot have non-constant expressions as cases in your switch statement. However, you can make the cases constant by subtracting `key` from `v1`:

```
switch (v1 - key) {
   case 0:
       .......
   case 1:
       .......
   case 2:
       .......
   default:
       .......
}
```

However, this only works because you have simple cases. As @BorisTheSpider points out, in the more general case, you'd need to use `if...else` statements.